# Item's ClickListener disable HighLight on Item touch

Tags: android

I have List of items. I'm using custom adapter (Android 1.5).
Everything works perfectly, until I reached the point when I add item's ClickListener to each Item.

When I do that, I lose the "focus effect", when the user touch at any item.

The mechanism works fine, but **visually** I cant see the red background which surrounding the item when the user clicks on it.

Any idea why?

Some code:

my arrayAdapter:

```
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {
    private ArrayList<Order> items;
    private Context mContext;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
        super(mContext, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        Order o = items.get(position);
        v.setOnClickListener((new OnItemClickListener(position, o)));
        if (o != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TxtType);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeCreated);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText("סוג תעודה מזהה: " + o.getIdType());
        }
        if (bt != null) {
            bt.setText("זמן יצירת התמונה: " + o.getCreateDate());
        }
        return v;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int mPosition;
        private Order mItem;

        OnItemClickListener(int position, Order item) {
            mPosition = position;
            mItem = item;
            //mItem.setmChecked(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int x = mPosition;
            int z = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

this is the row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/certificate"
        android:id="@drawable/certificate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="1sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/TxtType"
            android:text="סוג תעודה מזהה"/>

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeCreated"
            android:text="זמן יצירת התמונה"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas will be welcome,

Thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why are you writing the click listner in the adapter. Instead you need to `setOnItemClickListner` for the listView inside the activity and handle it there. By doing this u will get the highlight since your individual list items will not have listeners anymore

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
    {
         // whatever u want do it here, not in the adapter.

    }
});
```

By doing this u will get your highlight back

NOTE: you need these imports.

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Comment: Please could you post some example? what do you mean inside the activity? which activity? and in which way.. thanks.

Comment: yourListView, how will I retrieve it in my Main activity, coz you said not to do any operation in the Adapter itself